# Find / Replace all files in namespace or folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring

I know I can do a find /replace by searching:

- Current Document
- Current Project
- Current Solution

Is there any way to do this by searching the current namespace or current folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using Visual Studio. To replace files in a folder just open the Find and Replace dialog, and press the "..." button in "Look in:" section.

Comment: interesting, have never used that. lol. You could always load them into temp projects (just the stuff you want to get renamed and use resharper & VS find/replace combo

Answer (score 0):

Kind of, in ReSharper you can use the Class View window to rename Namespaces, but other than that ... I think you are out of luck. Unless there is a VS plugin I am unaware of.